# Change several variables with value "None" to for example "n/a" inside a for loop

Tags: python, discord

I'm new to coding and I'm making a discord bot with Discord.py. I have a command that shows me info about an IP address i provide. The problem is. Some of the results wont always have info like for example the city and it just says "None". I tried to make a for loop that changes each value with "None" to "n/a", but it still returns "None" outside the loop.

I have tried googling around but haven't found any solution that works. It might be because I'm dumb or blind. The variable has the new value inside the loop, but not outside. Is it possible to change the value in a for loop to be used outside it or is it not possible? I know i can manually fix this for each variable, but it would be a lot better to be able to do it from a singe loop.

**The code:**

```py
@bot.command()
async def ip(msg, ctx):
    host = shodan.host(ctx)
    city = host.get('city')
    country = host.get('country_name')
    ipp = host['ip_str']
    org = host.get('org')
    os = host.get('os')
    hostname = str(host.get('hostnames')).strip("['']")
    ports = str(host.get('ports')).strip('[]')
    services = host.get('services')
    variables = [host, city, country, ipp, org, os, hostname, ports, services]
    for v in variables:
        if v == None:
            v = "n/a"
        await msg.channel.send(f"**City:** {city}\n**Country:** {country}\n**IP:** {ipp}\n**Organization:** {org}\n**Operating System:** {os}\n**Hostnames:** {hostname}\n**Ports:** {ports}\n**Services:** {services}")
```

**Example output:**

**City:** None
**Country:** Norway
**IP:** 195.88.54.16
**Organization:** Globalconnect
**Operating System:** None
**Hostnames:** www.vg.no
**Ports:** 80, 443
**Services:** None

The whole thing is just a small detail and not really important, but i would be really happy if anyone had a solution or any tips that could help me improve it.

Comment: You write `v = "n/a"` and then proceed not to use the variable `v` anywhere

Comment: That's what i did?

Comment: `v` is not present in the string you're sending. And assigning like `v = "n/a"` creates a new variable called `v` - it doesn't modify the list `variables`

Comment: Ohhh ok i see. It makes sense now xd. Is there an way i can assign something to the variable then without knowing the name? Like a variable for the variable? I thought that was `v` but i clearly misunderstood how that works.

Comment: I think you could just do `services = host.get('services', 'n/a')`

Comment: I added `, n/a` behind `city`, `os` and `services`. It somehow only works for `services`. When printing out the types all of them says <class 'NoneType'>, and after adding `, n/a` only `services` would actually change both type and to n/a. Removing `, n/a` from services resulted inn none of them getting n/a.

Comment: No clue how this works lol. Thanks for the tip tho